# ld path update in centos

Tags: linux, centos, installation, path

I just installed *manually* **apr** and **apr_util** so i can install activemq cpp library.

When i try to **make** the cpp library i get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and expat is within apr-util and not being linked. how can i update the ld path so that make or environment will find it?

or in short: how can i resolve this?

Comment: `rpm -qa | grep expat`?

Comment: expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3
expat-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It looks like you need to install `expat-devel` package:

```
# yum install expat-devel
```

---

Add the library path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`) if you installed to non-standard location and run `ldconfig`.

Comment: no luck. it didnt help...

Comment: updated my answer.